# How can I have @Async work on 2 different threads for 2 different methods in Spring.?

Tags: spring, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-async

In my application I have 2 `@Async` methods: one for auditing purposes and another for updation of some maps in 2 entirely different beans, called from different beans but at same time. One from Audit listener and other from a controller.

My problem is that both of them run in a single thread, i.e first audit runs and then in the same thread those maps are created. So, if audit throws some exception, maps wont be created, or maps throw an error, audit wont get recorded.

Is there any way, I can have these 2 methods run in different Async threads.

Method1:

```
@Async(value="myExecutor")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void regenerateZoneMapAsync(DemandSource ds) {
    System.out.println("\n\n********************Current Thread in Async Class*****************" + Thread
            .currentThread());
    regenerateZmFilesByDs(ds);
    System.out.println("\n\n*********Current Thread********" + Thread.currentThread());
}
```

Method2:

```
@Async(value="myExecutor")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void callAudit(DemandSource ds) {
    System.out.println("\n\n************Current Thread in Audit Class*********" + Thread
            .currentThread());
    callAudit(ds);
    System.out.println("\n\n***********Current Thread********" + Thread.currentThread());
}
```

println has been added for my own clarity, to know which thread is been executed. I am new to both, multithreading and Spring.

My config class has

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor"/> 
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
```

After adding above configuration with `@Async(value="myExecutor")` my code has stopped working altogether, By this I mean,bean in which `regenerateZoneMapAsync()` has been defined, is not called from my calling bean, some proxy issue arises.

Edit:

One thing that comes in my mind is can it be possible that Audit thread completes its processing and send the thread back to pool, and then map picks the same thread and starts its processing.

Basically I want that if audit throws any error, and roll backs map updation should still happen.

Comment: Add your configuration to your question.

Comment: what part of configuration do you want exactly?

Comment: The configuration of the async and the thread pool configuration.

Comment: <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor"/>
    <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
After adding above configuration with @Async(value="myExecutor") my code has stopped working altogether

Comment: Please add the code as improvement to your question not as comments as that makes it completely unreadable not to mention the fact that people have to read everything to have a complete overview of the information.

Comment: Also add the code that is calling the 2 async methods. I also wonder how did it stop working when adding `@Async(value="myExecutor")`.

Comment: Not really `callAudit` is calling itself... Next to that you haven't explained what stopped working and how that manifests (you only say it stopped working). How is this code being called?

Comment: Also for your usecase you don't really need multiple threads or async imho, just proper exception handling.

Comment: I already told that both my methods are called from entirely different beans. Plus I have added what have stopped working. Is there any way to start two different threads for 2 different Async ??

Comment: Still add that code and it is still  unclear what isn't working. You are only telling/showing snippets without completing the full picture. So quite hard to help you then. I expect that you have multiple instances of your beans making the `@Async` useless as you will have a proxied and unproved one. Also `@Async(value="myExecutor")` doesn't add anything as `myExecutor` is already the default executor.

Comment: Well my issue worked. The implicit thread executor creates 2 threads itself. It might be possible that I have earlier read wrong thread names, or my war wasn't updated. Any ways thanks. And I am closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got my answer.

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) always creates a new transaction if called from another bean.

If called from same bean, a new transaction is never made, and since it is @Async , it starts in the already running Async thread.

So, I had to make another bean for my method, and and the two methods started running in 2 different threads concurrently.

Got my reference from:

> @Async has two limitations:
>
> it must be applied to public methods only; 
>   self invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work;
>
> The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied.
>   And self-invocation doesn’t work because it bypasses the proxy and
>   calls the underlying method directly.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async